# Experimental Difference b/w Graphite Oxide & Graphene Oxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I'm looking forward to making a graphene supercapacitor using LightScribe method for 12th Grade project. I need **Graphite Oxide**, to start working although all I can find on the web is Graphene Oxide.

I've read [What is the difference between graphite oxide and graphene oxide?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4558/what-is-the-difference-between-graphite-oxide-and-graphene-oxide), but I don't seem to understand whether I can use it in my application or not.

The paper I'm referring to regarding the project is: [Making Graphene-Based Supercapacitors by LightScribe, Theint-Aung, Cornell College, Department of Physics, Mount Vernon, IA](https://www.cornellcollege.edu/physics-and-engineering/pdfs/phy-312/Theint-Aung.pdf)

### Questions

---

Q1. Can I use **graphene oxide** instead of **graphite oxide** to accomplish the end goal of producing graphene supercapacitors (production method could be different)?

Q2. Can I convert graphene oxide into graphite oxide, using some reaction?

**Note:** I have access to an "alright" quality chemistry lab at school (not US), so processes involving ultrasonic baths are out of question, I have access to only cheap equipment.

**P.S.:** If possible, could you also provide a link where I could learn a bit about the chemistry behind the reactions you are talking about in your answer?

Comment: You should edit your title to increase your question's potential!

Comment: @Mockingbird Is that better? Titles are one of the things I’m not strong at...